# jenkins UI messed up and error on UI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins version 1.613 and today I installed Multi-Branch Project Plugin and then the issue happens, suddenly the UI is messed up and I see a huge error message on the Jenkins UI.

I have logged into the Jenkins server and I  disabled and removed the plugin and restarted Jenkins server but It didn't solve my issue.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.613.jar!/lib/hudson/actions.jelly:39:70: <st:include> hudson/ExtensionListListener
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:103)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.613.jar!/lib/hudson/actions.jelly:39:70: <st:include> hudson/ExtensionListListener

       at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:745)

at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:289)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:99)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet$1.dispatch(JellyFacet.java:95)
... 60 more

    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/ExtensionListListenerat jenkins.branch.CustomOrganizationFolderDescriptor$HideGeneric.filter(CustomOrganizationFolderDescriptor.java:170)
at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.isEnabled(CredentialsProvider.java:1050)
at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.enabled(CredentialsProvider.java:1013)
at com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.ViewCredentialsAction.isVisible(ViewCredentialsAction.java:231)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTAndNode.value(ASTAndNode.java:55)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTExpression.value(ASTExpression.java:54)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTExpressionExpression.value(ASTExpressionExpression.java:56)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:74)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.expression.ExpressionSupport.evaluateRecurse(ExpressionSupport.java:61)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.expression.ExpressionSupport.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionSupport.java:71)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:97)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
... 117 more

    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.ExtensionListListener
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1376)
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 141 more
 Help us localize this page Page generated: Sep 14, 2017 12:59:15 PMREST APIJenkins ver. 1.613
```

Here is what the Jenkins UI looks like [image: Here is the jenkins UI looks like]

Comment: The current version of Jenkins is 2.78. Your Jenkins installation is severely out of date. I would recommend that you upgrade to the latest version as soon as possible. I bet it would fix this issue that you're having. Do you have backups of the jobs?

Comment: Actually I dont have backup for the jobs . Can I Upgrade to the latest without taking any backup ..? Is it safe ..?

Comment: I would first try to install the Thin Backups plugin for Jenkins. After that I would run backups. Then I would upgrade to the latest version. I normally don't backup before upgrading, but I upgrade Jenkins on a regular basis, almost weekly. Upgrading a major version may be a little rocky. I'm not sure.

Comment: It happens when you usually update any plugin . So now you have to remove the Jenkins from your server or try to check which dependency updated with newer version.

Comment: What do you mean by removing jenkins from server..? And how can i check which dependancy got updated..? So finally. Which is the best way to solve this issue..? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are using old version of Jenkins, You have to upgraded it to latest one.
- Othen then this try to disable plugins and try. it might help

Answer (score 0):

go to Manage Jenkins => Manage Plugin => available => Maven Integration Plugin => than install that plugin and restart. it work fine for me.